# Log4j NoSQL/Mongo appender in Tibco BusinessWorks 5

Tags: log4j, tibco, tibco-business-works

What Log4J version is Tibco BusinessWorks 5 using?

And can I use the NoSQL appenders in that version? Can it be done without installing the Log4J 1-2 bridge?

Later update: It seems that so far changing the Log4J configuration file does not have too much effect. See [Changing Log4J configuration in Tibco BW/Designer does not have the desired effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386084/log4j-in-tibco-bw-designer-error).

Comment: What is the specific bw5 version are you using?

Comment: Adrain, are you able to check the answer to see if that is helpful?

Comment: I added my appender to `bw.logger`, beside the `tibco_bw_log` appender. The messages are sent to `tibco_bw_log`, but not to my appender. Even if I remove the `tibco_bw_log` appender from `bw.logger`, the logs are still going there and not to my logger. If I change my appender name to `tibco_bw_log` and removed the old appender then I was getting the error: "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender cannot be cast to com.tibco.share.util.BWLogFileAppender". Now I don't even get that error, but my appender does not get any logs.

Comment: I will ask another question on SO regarding this.

Comment: I explained in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386084/log4j-in-tibco-bw-designer-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with internal Tibco logging. Only Java activities can use custom loggers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it from below location of your `TIBCO` products installation.

Go to `../tibco/tpcl/<version>/lib` and look for `log4j.jar

And you do not have to install `log4j` explicitly.

I believe, you should be able to add your required appender in the file `../tibco/bw/<version>/lib/log4j.properties`. Also there is `lo4j.xml in case properties file does have worked. Try it out.

Comment: I modified both files log4j.properties and log4j.xml, but without success. Should I restart the engine? How?

Comment: You can stop it and start. See if you can stop the engine gracefully. Otherwise you may kill the process and start.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement [Rao's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887169/967606), you also need to add to restart your engines and make sure you added an appender to the right logger, namely `bw.logger` from either the `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`file.